# CSS grid make last column smaller

Tags: css

I'm learning the grid component in CSS and I was wondering if is it possible to have the last grid column having half the size of other (like to implement an action column that would not take much space.

Here is my codepen:

```css
.container{
      grid-template-columns: repeat(6, minmax(0px, 0.5fr));
      display: grid;
}

div{
  border:solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
  <div class="container">
      <div>A</div>
      <div>B</div>
      <div>C</div>
      <div>D</div>
      <div>E</div>
      <div>Remove</div>
      <div>A</div>
      <div>B</div>
      <div>C</div>
      <div>D</div>
      <div>E</div>
      <div>Remove</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the last column to be half sized and all the other columns taking as much space as possible.

I tried to play with the `grid-column` attribute by setting manually all the n divs start and end but it didn't help me. Should I maybe do it with a table, or with class divs?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `repeat(5, 1fr) 0.5fr;` in order to repeat 5 times 1fr and than set the last column to 0.5fr (half the size):

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr) 0.5fr;
}

div {
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
    <div>C</div>
    <div>D</div>
    <div>E</div>
    <div>Remove</div>
    <div>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
    <div>C</div>
    <div>D</div>
    <div>E</div>
    <div>Remove</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much!